# display each textbox value in new page of the report viewer?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, reportviewer

I have created a Report Viewer using VB.Net.

I have created a form wich has 9 optional textboxes. If user input 2 textbox, 3, and so on, I'm looking on how to show each textbox value entered in different page for print. 
I already know how to show only entered values in same page, but I can not find a solution on how to show each txtbox value (if entered) in pages separately

I use this code to show customer info, but I Need to show separately for each textbox entered value:

```
        Dim paramName As New ReportParameter("ParamName", customer.NameTxt.Text)
    Dim paramGender As New ReportParameter("ParamGender", customer.GenderTxt.Text)
    Dim paramAge As New ReportParameter("ParamAge", customer.AgeTxt.Text)

    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(paramName)
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(paramGender)
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(paramAge)

    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

Thanks In advance